# Matlab: is it possible to import data from ascii file and put them in a struct?

Tags: matlab, struct, matlab-struct

I have a file like this (param.txt):

```
JSS 2
ADEV 1
VERS 770
JSD 1
```

And I want to put the data from this file into a struct with a variable in my workplace.

Let say I call it "P", then P is the struct of:

```
Field    Value
_____  |_______
JSS    |2  
ADEV   |1  
VERS   |770  
JSD    |1
```

Then:

```
>>> P.JSS
ans = 
2
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It is possible. But you will have to read and parse the file by hand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `textscan` to grab all of the parts and then create your cell using the `struct` constructor.

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt', 'r');

% Parse out the fieldnames and numbers
data = textscan(fid, '%s %d');

% Put the strings in the first row and the numbers in the second
alldata = [data{1}, num2cell(data{2})].';

% Pass fieldnames and values to struct()
P = struct(alldata{:});

fclose(fid);
```